# Building with Eclipse and Remote System Explorer

Tags: windows, linux, eclipse, clearcase

First with the background...

- We have a Linux server that supports multiple projects.
- The Clearcase server and repository are installed on this Linux server.
- Different projects require different cross-compilers and libraries, and all of them are installed on the server.
- User can choose different tool sets by running different scripts, which exports different environment variable values such as include paths and compilers.
- User needs to run cleartool to mount the repository.
- Developers develop in Eclipse and have two options:

  1. SSH into the server and run Eclipse through with X11 tunneling.
  2. Install Eclipse locally on their Windows machine and invoke builds from the SSH terminal.

Now:

- Problem with #1 is that Eclipse operations (typing, content assist, etc) are extremely laggy.
- Problem with #2 is that the developers need to go through extra hoops to build their code.

This is what I have tried:

- Set up Remote System Explorer, which allows remote editing of files and remote running of the compiler:
  [How to build a c++ project on a remote computer in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856444/how-to-build-a-c-project-on-a-remote-computer-in-eclipse)

This approach works perfectly for files that do not need special environment variable values and mounting of Clearcase repository, but I could not figure out how to get all of these things to integrate.

It would be great if someone can let me know how I can direct RSE to run a script (may be different per project) to set the environment variables and to run the cleartool commands to mount the repository so that it can locate the files.
The cleartool command arguments would be different per user for setting up a particular view.

Some extra info that may help:

- I have root access to the development server
- The Clearcase filesystem is mapped to a drive on the Windows machine

Thanks in advance for saving me hours of frustration dealing with a slow network!

==================

Additional detail per comments:
- The VOB storage is located locally on the Linux server. We would SSH to the server and start Eclipse there, therefore the delay should not be due to dynamic vs snapshot view and GUI performance seems to be the real problem.
- We also mount the same view on Windows by using Region Synchronizer. When running the local copy of Eclipse installed on Windows, there is no performance problems.

So this question can probably be solved by answering either question:
1. How to improve X11 performance such that development on Linux will suffice?
2. How to set up Windows Eclipse to perform all the steps mentioned above when building projects?

Comment: Quick comment: that ClearCase view mapped for a drive, is it a dynamic one? Because a snapshot one would be *much* quicker for read access time and compilations.

Answer (score 0):

I came here a similar question to your part two, but alas, no one has answered it. However, I have an answer to your part one: https://www.nomachine.com/. It speeds up X11 forwarding considerably.