# Remote C development on a UNIX machine from a Windows machine using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, aix, remote-access, xlc

I have terminal access to an AIX machine using ssh/telnet (No root access). I need to develop programs using C and compile it using the xlc compiler. Currently I can open remote files in eclipse(Juno) using RSE and edit files, but code-completion and error checking won't work. Can anyone please, help me to setup eclipse, so that code-completion would work and also, I would be able to compile the code from my Windows machine. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Did you open your source files from a C project?

Comment: This one may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856444/how-to-build-a-c-project-on-a-remote-computer-in-eclipse?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this, http://wiki.eclipse.org/PTP/rdt-setup or.. check out...

[How to build a c++ project on a remote computer in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856444/how-to-build-a-c-project-on-a-remote-computer-in-eclipse)

Somewhat similar. If you look at the 3rd answer.

Also you could try X11 Forwarding -

http://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-x-forwarding

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to setup Eclipse and CDT to do remote development, you may want to consider purchasing IBM Rational Developer for Power Systems Software (RDP), which is an Eclipse-based remote development environment that allows for C and C++ (and COBOL) application development on AIX from a Windows or Linux system.  More information can be found [here](http://www.ibm.com/software/rational/products/rdp).